# Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'std::vector<bool, std::allocator<bool>>' (stl_vector.h)

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve the ["Number of Islands"](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-islands/) problem on Leetcode, but I'm getting this error.

Here is my code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    
    void dfs(vector<vector<char>>& grid,int i,int j, vector<vector<bool>>&vis){
        
    if(i<0 || i>=grid.size() || j<0 || j>=grid[0].size() || grid[i][j]=='1' || vis[i][j]==true  )return;
        
        vis[i][j]=true;
        dfs(grid,i+1,j,vis);
        
        dfs(grid,i,j+1,vis);

        dfs(grid,i,j-1,vis);

        dfs(grid,i-1,j,vis);
        

        
        
    }

    int numIslands(vector<vector<char>>& grid) {
        
        if(grid.size()==0)return 0;
        
        vector<vector<bool>>vis;
        for(int i=0;i<grid.size();i++){
            for(int j=0;j<grid[i].size();j++){
                vis[i][j]=false;
            }
        }
        int count=0;
        
        for(int i=0;i<grid.size();i++){
            for(int j=0;j<grid[i].size();j++){
                if(vis[i][j]== false && grid[i][j]=='0'){
                     count++;
                  dfs(grid,i,j,vis);
                   
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
};
```

Please review the code and tell me what's wrong.

Also, I am getting this error in almost every graph question.

Comment: `vis[i][j]=false;`: `vis` is an empty vector

Comment: you have to reserve the correct number of elemts in 'vis'

Comment: Don't use `[]`, user `at()`